# "Человек двенадцать-пятнадцать" – можно ли оставить дефис?

Tags: пунктуация, числительные, дефис-тире

> Курс на актёрском факультете обычно небольшой – человек
> двенадцать-пятнадцать, так что все студенты школы-студии при
> **Московском Художественном академическом театре МХАТ имени А. П. Чехова** играли в этом монументальном произведении различные массовые
> формирования – то людей на митинге, то солдат, то сподручников или
> сподвижников, то русский народ под гнётом Империи.

Непременно ли тире?..

---

Справка, как в ней разобраться:

> Моско́вский Худо́жественный теа́тр имени А. П. Че́хова (МХТ) —
> драматический театр.
>
> Образовался в 1987 году в результате раздела МХАТ СССР им. М.
> Горького. Имя Чехова носит с 1989 года. Слово «академический» не
> используется театром с 2004 года, хотя осталось в его официальном
> названии. Расположен в Москве в историческом здании МХТ (Камергерский
> переулок, дом 3).

Comment: Дефис - а как без него? Наверное, лучше "двенадцать-пятнадцать человек" (с "человека" обычно начинается одна приблизительная цифра), а здесь вышла двойная неопределённость, более характерная для разговорного стиля, когда второе число добавлено по ходу мысли (двенадцать, а то и пятнадцать). Судя по полному наименованию театра, здесь строгий, книжный стиль.

Comment: Саша, если я задам вопрос отдельно по названию театра, поможете? разберётесь? И... страшео спросить... Вы тире с дефисом путаете? О_о

Comment: Я ни разу не видел, чтобы "два-три дня" писалось через тире (в голову не пришло бы правило искать), здесь просто числа другие. А что с названием театра?

Comment: Са-а-аша!!! Так то ж совсем другой случай: БЕЗ ПРОПУСКА ЦИФР(Ы) внутри! А у меня аж две пропущено!

Comment: Решает акцент на приблизительность: это не инструкция держать число студентов в пределах таких-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дефис оставить нельзя. Это так называемое "соединительное тире":

> 1. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов (‘в значении от … до’):
>
> [...]
>
> 3) количественных: Рукопись объёмом десять — двенадцать авторских листов (то же цифрами: 10 — 12); Груз массой 300 — 350 тонн; 5 — 7-кратное превосходство.

См. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95).

Answer (score 3):

**Розенталь разрешает ставить дефис**

**Соединительное тире** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95

Примечание. Если между двумя рядом стоящими числительными можно вставить не слова от…до, а слово или, то числительные соединяются дефисом: Пробудет в командировке пять-шесть дней (но при цифровом обозначении ставится тире: …5 — 6 дней).

Comment: Очевидно, что в данном контексте курс "от 12 до 15 человек" (а не "или 12, или 15 человек").

Comment: Спасибо, Жасмин. В Вашем примере *пять-шесть* нет пропуска цифр, который есть в 12--15. Я просто надеялась: может, сойдёт? )))

Comment: Пробудет в командировке пять-шесть дней, то есть приблизительно (у Розенталя). А человек двенадцать-пятнадцать  с перестановкой - это вообще форма  обозначения приблизительного числа.